# Is this sentence, containing "struck upon", grammatically wrong?

Tags: grammar

This is the sentence:

> The purpose of this paper, however, is not to pass any serious criticism upon Pragmatism, which indeed is superfluous, but to point out the resemblance which has struck upon me between this popular philosophy and a sort of mentality satirised in a popular novel.

I think this sentence is grammatically wrong, because the idiom "struck upon" is used incorrectly and that made the sentence inapprehensible. Am I right?

Comment: I wouldn't say that the grammar is wrong, but it's rather poorly worded.

Comment: Where is the quote from? The capitalisation of Pragmatism and the general style of the English make me think that it's a piece of nineteenth century writing.

Comment: It’s from a 20th century Chinese writer. English was his second language. He didn’t stay in an English-speaking country for too long and he’s not known for his English writings. That’s why I think sometimes his English is grammatically wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The grammar is indeed wrong. A preposition introduces an indirect object.

> I leapt upon the bed.
> He hit the ball into the room.

Some verbs change their meaning with a preposition.

> He hit me.
> He hit on me.

*Strike* needs a direct object, *strike me* (or "struck me" ). *Strike upon me* is at best a pleonasm and at worst ungrammatical. However, it's understandable.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I checked Oxford Dictionary and found an idiom “be struck on sb/sth”. It means “be favourably impressed by sb/sth; like sb/sth very much”. The example is “He’s very much struck on his new girl-friend”. However, the sentence in the main thread doesn’t use the passive form. That’s why I think it’s wrong. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

> but to point out the resemblance which has struck upon me between this popular philosophy and a sort of mentality satirised in a popular novel.

The preposition "upon" must be omitted:

to strike (one/someone)

OED

> **64.** transitive. **Of a thought, an idea: To come into the mind of, occur to (a person). Frequently in the phrase it strikes (or it struck) me that —.**
>
> 1827   W. Scott Highland Widow v   *The first idea that struck him was, that the passenger belonged to his own corps.*

MW:

> **strike *on/upon*** phrasal verb
>
> : **to find or discover (something) especially suddenly**
>
> *He struck on an idea for his novel.*
>
> *They struck upon a salt mine.*